# How do I calculate the average on an Access report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I have been trying to insert data for the average net income I've got into a report but I can't figure out how to do it without it placing the data in all the other rows like in the picture. I just want to place individual text in the boxes underlined without them all saying the same thing

[image: picture]

Comment: You cannot add data to a report manually . Either change it to a form, or edit the query.

Comment: Right, cannot input into textbox on report. And whatever text you put into the ControlSource property of a textbox will show in ALL instances of the textbox. If you want the display to be variable then it must be bound to field or have an expression using some variable input such as reference to another field.

Answer (score 0):

If the net income value is available in your underlying data set and you're using grouping to get the Housing Community row, you should be able to use `=AVG([NetIncome])` in the control source of the average net income text box.

If the net income information isn't available in the report's data set and you don't want to add it, you could use a DAvg function in the control source of the average net income text box:

```
=DAvg("[NetIncomeColumn]", "[TableName]", "[Housing Community] = '" & [Housing Community Control Name] & "'")
```

It will be more efficient to get the net income data into the report's data set. The DAvg function will perform poorly as the amount of data reported increases.